Drag image to another image
I write this code to move image to another place but when I moving the image each point create new box so I get like this view:
Image box duplicate each moving step. But I cant find the solution for this.

import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from test import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.boxes = []  # Klonlanmış box'ların listesi

        self.original_box = QPixmap("box.png").scaled(100, 150)  # Orjinal box resmi
        self.original_palette = QPixmap("palette.png")
        # print( self.img.width(),self.img.height())
        self.ui.image.setPixmap(self.original_box)
        self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

        self.dragging = False  # Sürükleme durumu
        self.offset = None  # Sürükleme konumu
        self.ui.image.setFixedSize(self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
        self.ui.palet.setFixedSize(self.original_palette.width(), self.original_palette.height())
        # self.ui.image.setScaledContents(True)
        self.ui.image.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.ui.image.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")

        self.ui.palet.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.ui.palet.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")
        print("After")
        self.ui.widget_2.setAcceptDrops(True)  # Bırakma işlemini kabul et

        self.last_offset = None

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.painterInstance = QPainter(self.original_palette)

        # set rectangle color and thickness
        self.penRectangle = QPen(Qt.red)
        self.penRectangle.setWidth(3)

        # draw rectangle on painter
        self.painterInstance.setPen(self.penRectangle)

        # Sürüklenen box'ı çiz
        if self.dragging :
            # if self.last_offset != None:
                # self.painterInstance.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Source)
                # self.painterInstance.fillRect(QRect(self.offset, self.original_box.size()), Qt.transparent)
                # self.painterInstance.fillRect(QRect(self.last_offset, self.original_box.size()), Qt.transparent)

                # self.painterInstance.eraseRect(QRect(int(self.last_offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                #                                      int(self.last_offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                #                                      self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height()))
                #
                # self.painterInstance.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Source)
                # self.painterInstance.fillRect(QRect(self.last_offset, self.original_box.size()), Qt.transparent)

            # print(self.dragging)

            # painter.drawPixmap(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
            #                    int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
            #                    self.original_box)

            # self.painterInstance.drawRect(500, 360, 50, 50)
            self.painterInstance.drawPixmap(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                                            int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2), self.original_box)

            self.last_offset = self.offset

            # set pixmap onto the label widget
            self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

            # self.ui.image.setPixmap(self.original_box)
            # self.relase = False
            # self.dragging = False

        # Klonlanmış box'ları çiz
        # for box in self.boxes:
        #     self.painterInstance.drawPixmap(box.topLeft(), self.original_box)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print(event.pos())
            # print("MAUSE GLOBAL POS",self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))
            # print(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())))
            print(self.ui.widget_2.rect())
            if(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))):
                self.dragging = True
                self.offset = event.pos()
                print("Offset point", self.offset)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.dragging:
            # print("DRAGGING")
            # Sürüklenen box'ın merkezini güncelle
            self.offset = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.dragging:
            self.dragging = False
            print("RELEASE")
            self.relase = True
            # Yeni box'ı oluştur
            new_box = QRect(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                            int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                            self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
            # self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)
            # self.ui.palet.show()
            self.boxes.append(new_box)
            self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())    

I try this in paint method:
def paintEvent(self, event):
    self.painterInstance = QPainter(self.original_palette)

    # set rectangle color and thickness
    self.penRectangle = QPen(Qt.red)
    self.penRectangle.setWidth(3)

    # draw rectangle on painter
    self.painterInstance.setPen(self.penRectangle)

    # Sürüklenen box'ı çiz
    if self.dragging :
        if self.last_offset != None:
            self.painterInstance.eraseRect(QRect(int(self.last_offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                                                    int(self.last_offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                                                    self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height()))
            #
            # self.painterInstance.setCompositionMode(QPainter.CompositionMode_Source)
            # self.painterInstance.fillRect(QRect(self.last_offset, self.original_box.size()), Qt.transparent)

        # print(self.dragging)

        # painter.drawPixmap(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
        #                    int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
        #                    self.original_box)

        # self.painterInstance.drawRect(500, 360, 50, 50)
        self.painterInstance.drawPixmap(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                                        int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2), self.original_box)

        self.last_offset = self.offset

        # set pixmap onto the label widget    

I get this result, erase the background.

How can I solve this problem. I almost close the solution but I cant do the draw related place.
EDIT - 2:
By the way if I use the region as a mainwindow like this  this code
move the object with It creates, destroys and re-creates the object at each step. But I can't do this on a layer, actually I should be able to do it.:
   import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint


class Rectangle(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Klonlanabilir Boxlar')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        self.boxes = []  # Klonlanmış box'ların listesi
        self.original_box = QPixmap("box.png").scaled(300, 400)  # Orjinal box resmi
        self.dragging = False  # Sürükleme durumu
        self.offset = None  # Sürükleme konumu

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)

        # Orjinal box'ı çiz
        painter.drawPixmap(100, 100, self.original_box)

        # Sürüklenen box'ı çiz
        if self.dragging:
            painter.drawPixmap(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2,
                               self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2,
                               self.original_box)

        # Klonlanmış box'ları çiz
        for box in self.boxes:
            painter.drawPixmap(box.topLeft(), self.original_box)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            if QRect(100, 150, self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height()).contains(event.pos()):
                self.dragging = True
                self.offset = event.pos()
                print("Offset point",self.offset)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.dragging:
            # Sürüklenen box'ın merkezini güncelle
            self.offset = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.dragging:
            self.dragging = False
            # Yeni box'ı oluştur
            new_box = QRect(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2,
                            self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2,
                            self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
            self.boxes.append(new_box)
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Rectangle()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


You're continuously drawing over the same pixmap. The concept is similar to physical painting: the pixmap is the canvas, if you draw something it doesn't clear what you draw before, if you clear an area it doesn't restore what was there before. Looking at your code and your previous question, you should probably avoid the direct paint approach, and consider the Graphics View Framework instead.

@musicamante I want to do a move so I thought this was what I needed. If you have a solution suggestion, can you share it? I couldn't reach the solution.

Consider what written above: a "pixmap" (not specifically QPixmap) is a representation of pixels, each one having a different color. This is not so different from a physical canvas on which you paint: if you have a painting of a house, you cannot just take its door and move it. As said, what you're probably looking for is a dynamic and logical representation of objects, which is one the purposes of the Graphics View Framework. We cannot provide you examples based on conceptual problems like yours, as that's not the scope of SO, so I suggest you do some patient research on those topics.

@musicamante But when I move, I plan to keep the original box picture and move it more than once. So it has to be redrawn somehow. I've been looking at the Graphicview library for 3 days, but I couldn't find a solution. If you have a solution suggestion, can you please share it as code, how should I do it?

by the way I add edit-2 part of the topic

@CihanKOÇAR Sorry but I cannot share any code, as it would require me to completely write from scratch an example based on assumptions, which would be more similar to a tutorial than an actual answer, and that's not the purpose of StackOverflow, as already explained in my previous comment. Consider that passing 3 days on the Graphics View framework means barely scratching its surface. What you want can be done, but requires experience and knowledge that you cannot hope to get in a few days: considering your usage of paintEvent(), you have to be much more patient in your learning.

@CihanKOÇAR There are lots of possible ways to achieve what you want, most of them would probably use QGraphicsView, but that doesn't mean that you only need that. You may need more than one, or consider further widgets (such as QToolBar), and even work with drag&drop. It's clear that you're in the beginning of your learning process of Qt, which is an extremely huge and extensible toolkit. While nobody expects you to become an expert and write perfect "Qt based code" in a few weeks, looking for shortcuts and workarounds that result in bad implementations won't be effective. Be patient.

I solved my problem with this code:
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from test import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint





class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.boxes = []  # Klonlanmış box'ların listesi

        self.original_box = QPixmap("box.png").scaled(100, 150)  # Orjinal box resmi
        self.original_palette = QPixmap("palette.png")
        # print( self.img.width(),self.img.height())
        self.ui.image.setPixmap(self.original_box)
        self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

        self.dragging = False  # Sürükleme durumu
        self.offset = None  # Sürükleme konumu
        self.ui.image.setFixedSize(self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
        self.ui.palet.setFixedSize(self.original_palette.width(), self.original_palette.height())
        # self.ui.image.setScaledContents(True)
        self.ui.image.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.ui.image.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")

        # self.ui.palet.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        # self.ui.palet.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")
        print("After")
        self.ui.widget_2.setAcceptDrops(True)  # Bırakma işlemini kabul et
        self.firstMove = False



        self.last_offset = None
    def paintEvent(self, event):


        self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

        painter = QPainter(self.ui.palet.pixmap())

        if self.dragging :
            # self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

            painter.drawPixmap(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                               int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                               self.original_box)

        for box in self.boxes:
            painter.drawPixmap(box.topLeft(), self.original_box)



    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print(event.pos())
            # print("MAUSE GLOBAL POS",self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))
            # print(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())))
            if(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))):
                self.dragging = True
                self.offset = event.pos()
                self.firstMove = True
                print("Offset point", self.offset)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.dragging:
            # print("DRAGGING")
            print(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))
            # Sürüklenen box'ın merkezini güncelle
            self.offset = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.dragging:
            self.dragging = False

            print("RELEASE")
            self.relase = True
            # Yeni box'ı oluştur
            new_box = QRect(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                            int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                            self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
            # self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)
            # self.ui.palet.show()

            self.boxes.append(new_box)
            self.update()
            self.boxes[-1].moveCenter(self.offset)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)


    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

This part solved my problem:
 def paintEvent(self, event):


        self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

        painter = QPainter(self.ui.palet.pixmap())

        if self.dragging :
            # self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

            painter.drawPixmap(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                               int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                               self.original_box)

        for box in self.boxes:
            painter.drawPixmap(box.topLeft(), self.original_box)

I can drag and drop into this palet image:

But I have little problem here, when I click the box it detects but this create on here:

I think I have problem with event.pos() how can I solve this ?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

the method paintEvent redraw the entire widget when there's a change. eraseRect is removing the previous box but not working as expected
   def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.original_palette)

        # ... any other code here ...

        if self.dragging:
            # OPTION 1
            # clear the entire pixmap fr clean redraw
            self.original_palette.fill(Qt.transparent)  # Clear the palette

            # draw the image at the new position
            painter.drawPixmap(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                               int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                               self.original_box)

            #OPTION 2
            # Clear the area where the image was previously drawn
            clear_rect = QRect(int(self.last_offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                          int(self.last_offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                          self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
            self.original_palette.fill(Qt.transparent, clear_rect)

        # update the label with the modified pixmap
        self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)


Clear the Palette: In the paintEvent, when dragging is active, clear the entire original_palette pixmap using self.original_palette.fill(Qt.transparent). This should ensures a clean canvas for redrawing

redrawing: use the painter to draw the original_box pixmap at the new position calculated based on the offset

Update Label: update the ui.palet label with the modified original_palette pixmap



If I use this line self.original_palette.fill(Qt.transparent) palet image removing in screen. I get this result https://ctrl.vi/i/DNbgsDR6r

I've added an option 2: how does it works?

I get this error now    self.original_palette.fill(Qt.transparent, clear_rect)
TypeError: fill(self, color: Union[QColor, Qt.GlobalColor] = Qt.GlobalColor.white): too many arguments

I think this is not correct using for the fill function

I think filler function take only one parameter and it's color . @Gigino

This is not really appropriate. The paintEvent() should be responsible of the actual painting of the widget, while right now it's actually used for a different (and, therefore, wrong) purpose, which is updating a QPixmap and setting it on another widget: in fact, the paintEvent() above does not paint anything at all on the widget in which it's implemented (the main window). Besides, it's normally wrong to draw on the top level window, and a dedicated "canvas" (normally, a QWidget subclass) should be used instead, which then overrides its own paintEvent().

@musicamante So how should I do?
